# What's the difference between clear and arrayValue in jsoncpp

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

To work with json using a library jsoncpp. Previously created an array of objects can be cleared by `clear`.

```
Json::Value value;
...
value.clear();
```

Also, it can be purified by `arrayValue` (or `nullValue`).

```
Json::Value value;
...
value = Json::arrayValue;
```

Question: What's the difference between `clear` and `arrayValue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

null, empty array, and empty object are three different things in JsonCpp.

`value.clear()` does the following:

- null -> null
- any array -> empty array
- any object -> empty object
- anything else -> throw std::runtime_error

`value = Json:arrayValue` does the following:

- anything -> empty array

So the two constructs are not semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Clear= Remove all object members and array elements.

nullvalue = Means a empty value.

Comment: The principal difference in what? Can I use arraiValyue instead of clear? If not - why?

Comment: I think it doesnt matter. Its like the difference between while loop and for loop. Both do the same functions just a small difference. Play around with both.